# Search in array of precise positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, graph

I currently have a painting with 64 tiles, each color is defined. Grey is a valid position, black is an invalid position (a wall), green is player pawn 1 and red is player pawn 2. When player 1 clicks on his green pawn he can choose to duplicate himself on a valid tile close to him (Grey) or jump on the 2nd tile close to him. If ever the green pawn is a tile close to the red pawn it becomes green Now what I'm looking for is.

How to search for all valid positions either a ready tile or jump on the 2nd and correctly checked what is there afterwards.

[image]

```
class Game{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.default_grid = null;
            this.curr_grid_playing = null;
            this.player = 1;
            this.curr_player_turn = 1;
            this.game_is_ready = false;
            this.rows = [];

            this.do_new_game();
        }

        get_random_grid(){
            const array_grid = [
                "3100000010000000000000000003300000033000000000000000000200000023",
                "1000000200300300033003300000000000000000033003300030030010000002",
                "0000000000000000033300300313203003013230030033300000000000000000",
                "0000000000000000003033000313003003230030003033000000000000000000"
            ];
            return array_grid[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_grid.length)];
        }

        do_new_game(){
            this.default_grid = this.get_random_grid();
            this.curr_grid_playing = this.default_grid;
            
            for(let i = 0; i < this.default_grid.length; i++){   
                if(i % 8 == 0)
                    this.rows.push([]);
                this.rows[this.rows.length - 1].push([i, this.default_grid.charAt(i)]);

                let new_game_node = this.create_game_button(this.default_grid.charAt(i), i);
                this.append_child_node(new_game_node);
                
            }     
        }

        get_grid_possibilities(from_index){
            if(this.curr_player_turn == 1 && (this.curr_player_turn == this.player)){
               console.log(this.rows);
               
            } else if(this.curr_player_turn == 2 && (this.curr_player_turn == this.player)){

            }
        }
    }
```

I was thinking about making a graphic in a array to represent exactly the grid
< this.rows > is what our console displays, it works, but I'm not sure exactly if it's not too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the matrix representing your board game, so you just have to check for the -1 and +1 squares.

```
let characterPosition = {x:5, y:5};

for (let row-1; row<=1; row++) {
    for (let col-1; col<=1; col++) {
        
        let testPosX = characterPosition.x + col;
        let testPosY = characterPosition.y + row;
        
        if (row===0 && col===0) {
            // player pos -> skip
            break;
        }
        
        if (testPosX<0 || testPosY<0 || testPosY>matrix.length-1 || testPosX>matrix[0].length-1) {
            // outside board -> skip
            break;
        }
        
        if (matrix[testPosY][testPosX]===0) {
            // this is a empty square
        } else {
            // this is not an empty square
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about jump on the 2nd tile close to him.

Comment: If you can jump, then simply use -2 and +2. If you can't, you'll need to program a pathfinder by moving and checking step by step.